# Shifting while in neutral

Tags: transmission, shifting

I am new to motorcycles and I just bought a 2010 Triumph Thruxton 900. I am having difficulty cycling through all the gears in neutral. I haven’t taken it to higher gears on the road yet but should I be able to shift through all the gears?

Stephen

Comment: Not sure your question is clear - neutral is neutral... You go through it to get to another gear... But I don't see how you "cycle though all the gears" while in neutral.

Comment: Should I be able to shift from 1-N-2-3-4-5-6 while holding the clutch?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you should be able to shift into 1st and 2nd whilst stationary, above gear 2 the bike would need to be moving to get into a higher gear(my experience from riding many different bikes).
Why did you buy a 900 if your new to bikes?
Ride safe

Comment: You’re right probably not the smartest move. Definitely going to take it slow.

Comment: Watch out for others on the road, take it easy and enjoy